# Generalized Infinite Integration by Parts

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

During my studies in calc 2, I became fascinated by the integral $\int e^{-x^2}dx$ after hearing from the professor that it has no elementary function as its integral. I came up with an interesting technique to try the integral by using Integration by Parts like so: $$\int e^{-x^2}dx=xe^{-x^2}+2\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx $$ $$\int e^{-x^2}dx=xe^{-x^2}+\frac {2} {3}x^3e^{-x^2}+\int x^4e^{-x^2}dx$$
and continuing this until the pattern became obvious and I came up with the following equation: $$\int e^{-x^2}dx=e^{-x^2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 
\frac {2^i} {(2i+1)!!}x^{2i+1}+C$$ where $(2i+1)!!$ denotes the double factorial $(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)...(2 \text{ or } 1)$.  From here, I thought about a generalized case for any infinitely differentiable function $f(x)$ and for an argument raised to any power $n$.  $$\int f(x^n)dx $$ $$u=f(x^n), du=nx^{n-1}f'(x^n), dv=dx, v=x$$ $$\int f(x^n)dx=xf(x^n)-n\int x^nf'(x^n)dx$$ and eventually: $$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-n)^{i}x^{ni+1}} {(ni+1)(n(i-1)+1)...(n+1)(1)}f^{(i)}(x^n)+C$$ My question is twofold. First, did I make any glaring mistakes, and second, is this particular formula useful or novel?

Comment: repeated integration by parts is a way we get asymptotic expansions http://store.doverpublications.com/0486650820.html

Comment: Your $du$ is off.  Should be $nx^{n-1}f'(x^n)$.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing what you're doing when the taylor series of $e^{x}$ is known and you just integrate that.

Comment: @Geronimo I don't understand why anyone interested in math would *not* do this, if it occurred to them.

Comment: I would also like to encourage OP—who, bear in mind, is a Calc 2 student—to continue to investigate and ponder questions about things seen in class.

Comment: I can't determine it but can you express the bottom of your expression as a falling or rising factorial? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials somehow..

Comment: This is brilliant if it comes out from a Calc 2 student's mind! After correcting the mistake pointed out by the answer below, you can try to write a formula of n-times 'by-part', and then prove it rigorously by mathematical induction as an exercise.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is totally not useful, but this is almost the same as Taylor series. If you haven't learnt/seen Taylor series, you may regard that you have discovered something quite novel (to you)!

Comment: I appreciate the words, by I have a rule to remind that: no one can take steal (though there's one exception) my work, as everybody knows who's work it is.

Comment: Though, there isn't really a lot of  work done yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your $du$ again in $$ u=f(x^n), du=nx^{n-1}f(x^n), dv=dx, v=x$$

Also check this formula $$  \int f(x^n)dx=xf(x^n)-n\int x^nf(x^n)dx$$

What is the advantage of your method in comparison with integrating the Taylor series  of a function?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes- they have been corrected.  As for your question, I was just recently playing around with it on a graphing calculator and at least for the original function I was integrating it appears to converge faster than the corresponding taylor series.

Comment: Thanks for your attention